# creating a loop that draw the person three times, moving the person dX dY?

Tags: java

java code. Im confused with this question

*6. Now put a loop in your paintComponent method that draws the person three times, moving him (her?) 
150 or so pixels each time (you decide how far)*

Do i need to create a scanner in Jframe to ask user to how much he or she want to move the person and they can only move the person 3 times? 
help

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
public class DrawPersonPanel extends JPanel {

private final int WIDTH = 600;
private final int HEIGHT = 400;
private int headX = 60;
private int headY = 40;
private int[] hairX = {62,75,84,85,88,90,93,99,104,110};
private int[] hairY = {45,46,37,38,39,30,31,32,33,54};
private int[] shirtX = {60,0,20,60,50,130,120,160,180,120};
private int[] shirtY = {100,150,180,160,250,250,160,180,150,100};
private int[] zigzagX = {70,75,80,85,90,95,100,105,110};
private int[] zigzagY = {135,140,135,140,135,140,135,140,135};
private int[] pantsX = {50,130,150,110,90,70,30};
private int[] pantsY = {250,250,375,375,300,375,375};


//--------------------------------------
// Constructor: Set up the panel.
//--------------------------------------
public DrawPersonPanel()
{
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
}
//--------------------------------------
// Draw person
//--------------------------------------
public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
{
page.setColor(Color.blue);
page.fillPolygon(shirtX, shirtY, shirtX.length);

page.setColor(new Color(255, 228, 181));
page.fillOval(headX, headY, 60, 60 - 10);


page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
page.fillPolygon(hairX, hairY, hairX.length);


page.setColor(Color.WHITE);
page.drawPolyline(zigzagX, zigzagY, zigzagX.length);


page.setColor(Color.cyan);
page.fillPolygon(pantsX, pantsY, pantsX.length);



}

private void movePerson(int x, int y){
// Increment head.
        headX += x;
        headY += y;

        for (int i = 0; i < hairX.length; i++) 
        {hairX[i] += x;}

        for (int i = 0; i < hairY.length; i++) 
        {hairY[i] += y;}

        // Increment shirt.
         for (int i = 0; i < shirtX.length; i++) 
        {shirtX[i] += x;}

        for (int i = 0; i < shirtY.length; i++) 
        {shirtY[i] += y;}

        // Increment zig-zag on shirt.
        for (int i = 0; i < zigzagX.length; i++) 
        {zigzagX[i] += x;}

        for (int i = 0; i < zigzagY.length; i++) 
        {zigzagY[i] += y;}

        // Increment pants.
        for (int i = 0; i < pantsX.length; i++) 
        {pantsX[i] += x;}

        for (int i = 0; i < pantsY.length; i++) 
        {pantsY[i] += y;}


        repaint();

}



}
```

Comment: Are you asking us how to interpret your homework assignment?

Answer (score 0):

What the question is saying is to create a loop that calls the function movePerson 3 times by a fixed amount. They are just saying it can be any arbitrary amount that you pick (beforehand, while coding).

Answer (score 0):

Create one person where their left and right position depends on a variable, say X, and then make a for loop that increments X by the preset amount every time.

Like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 450; i+= 150){
    drawPerson(i, yValue);
}
```

where drawPerson is a function that draws the person at (i, yValue). This will draw three people, each 150 apart.

You can change how far apart they are by adjusting how much you increment i.

Just play with it until it works. Like Mark Zuckerberg said, "Move fast and break things"